# Error: non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context (Circle Program

Tags: java, constructor

I am working on a program that will compute the circumference and area of the circle with just asking for the diameter here is the first part:

```
public class Circle
{  
    private double diameter;
    public Circle (double dia)
    {diameter = 1;}
    public void setDiameter(double dia)
    {diameter = dia;}
    public double getDiameter()
    {return diameter;}
    public double calcPerimeter()
    {return 3.14 * diameter; }
    public double calcArea()
    {return 3.14 * (diameter / 2 * diameter / 2);}
}
```

this is the test that comes with the program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class CircleTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        double diameter;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the diameter of the circle:");
        diameter = keyboard.nextDouble();
        Circle circle1= new Circle(diameter);
        System.out.println("The circle's diameter is: " + Circle.getDiameter());
        System.out.println("The first circle's perimeter is: " + 
        Circle.calcPerimeter());
        System.out.println("The circle's area is: " + Circle.calcArea());
    }
}
```

It throws me error like :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8nBa.jpg)

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Circle circle1= new Circle(diameter);
    System.out.println("The circle's diameter is: " + circle1.getDiameter());
    System.out.println("The first circle's perimeter is: " + 
    Circle.calcPerimeter());
    System.out.println("The circle's area is: " + circle1.calcArea());
```

Use the variable instead of the class. You would have accessed `getDiameter` if it was a static method.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you so much, didn't notice that I used the class instead of the variable.